# how can I check if an external javascript has failed to load?

Tags: javascript, html, pageload

If I put a script tags `<script src="url"></script>` in the `head` section of the page like

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="url1"></script>
    <script src="url2"></script>
    <script src="url3"></script>
    <script src="url4"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

if some of them has failed to load, how can I detect the same and alert the user like

```
function scriptLoadFailed( url )
{
   alert( url + " loading failed!" );
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get answer in following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683824/detect-and-log-when-external-javascript-or-css-resources-fail-to-load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the top of your `<head>`

```
<script>
    function scriptfail(element) {
        alert('failed to load ' + element.src);
    }
</script>
```

In your script element

```
<script src="url1" onerror='scriptfail(this);'></script>
```